# Finding the voltage across an inductor in a RLC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, inductor, passive-networks

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image]

And I need to find the voltage at the node \$\text{Y}_1\$.

---

**My Work:**

The input voltage and current relation is given by:

$$\frac{10}{s}=i_{in}(s)\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{100+s76\cdot10^{-3}}+\frac{1}{100+\frac{1}{s6.8\cdot10^{-6}}}}\tag1$$

The current trough the resistor \$\text{R}_1\$ and inductor is given by:

$$i_L(s)=\frac{100+\frac{1}{s6.8\cdot10^{-6}}}{100+\frac{1}{s6.8\cdot10^{-6}}+100+s76\cdot10^{-3}}\cdot i_{in}(s)\tag2$$

And the voltage at the node \$Y_1\$ is than given by:

$$V_{Y_1}=s\cdot76\cdot10^{-3}\cdot i_L(s)\tag3$$

If I plot the solution I get:

[image]

> Question: Is this true?

Comment: After the switch is pressed and held or, after the switch is released (having been held for a long time)?

Comment: @Andyaka the switch is closed at t=0 and of will be closed

Comment: What is `s`? Either adding units or giving the actual formulas (with variables, not values) would be great for understanding...

Comment: Why has the capacitor got anything to do with Y1 then?

Comment: @SimSon s is the Laplace operator

Comment: @Andyaka well the input current is dependend on C

Comment: R2 and C1 have no effect on the  R1/L1 path, so they can be removed from the circuit. You can use the general method to determine the step response, and that gives the answer in 3 or 4 lines without recourse to Laplace transforms.

Comment: @Chu so is my calculation wrong?

Comment: @Jan, your calculation is much more complicated than it has to be. It looks like you found the complete source current, then used the current divider rule to find the inductor current, then multiply by the inductor impedance to find the voltage. That's about 2 extra steps and a heck of a lot of extra algebra you didn't need to do.

Comment: @Jan, Which calculation? I can't see anything from Jan.

Comment: But I've never used a Laplace transform since 1996 or so, so I'll leave showing you the simpler solution to somebody who prefers to work that way.

Comment: It appears that you have [created two accounts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accountshttps://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Please contact the SE staff about having them merged.